# IE and Safari cannot open/read/inflate gzipped CSS or JavaScript

Tags: coldfusion, gzip, coldfusion-10

I’ve run into a seemingly particular problem that I’ve been unable to figure out thus far.

I’ve gzipped a bunch of the static CSS and JavaScript files on our website for the client’s browser to consume.  I am using a ColdFusion page to check the Accept-Encoding to determine if the browser says it can inflate the .gz files.  If it cannot I send the regular .css or .js file.

After implementing this process I tested it on both my local and our dev environment with no issue in all major browsers with no problems.  However, **in our production environment only, Safari and IE cannot seem to inflate the gzipped files despite indicating they can when I check the Accept-Encoding.**

Here is a snip of what Safari reads the file as:

> > ¬�   !T
> >     common.css�}k��F��� �?�,4��#� �(�
> >     �8{�� ���־� n  %�JܖD-IuuY��~�Έ��$Um/p���.�̌�|E�;7���z����t�>��ݮ<=�o�թ =����r�}]��a��E��O�0�Sq�\���}m�S3j��||�V���-�i�:ز�ũ]��yy*j�D�_����ܵ���"=y ���d�Ku*��U����;�"[7�u]>�[��b���<< ���? �-]z�JOAi�� �� �� lPxJ bAOx�Mն�Q�Oƛꋪ�-S� � �~?��Q �,�� m��aw�5S�i��8�>
> >     �G ���ݫ.��(h�Q O>�_wes>�/�'��u�¬6Nى�K�F"y�] 
> >     T1 fE�  ¬�Į>

On all three servers are Windows machines, running ColdFusion 10 on tomcat. We are using IIS 7.5 on all servers as well.

After a lot of research last week, I’m no closer to an explanation/solution.

What I’ve read on the net as indicated that the “Transfer-Encoding: chunked” could be a problem.  I can see it listed in the response headers of IE (Safari lists it as Transfer-Encoding: Identity) and this header only appears there when looking at the production environment as well.

In relation to the Transfer-Encoding, when it is not present (local and dev) the Content-Length header comes through where it is not present when the “Transfer-Encoding: chunked” is there.

Also I can confirm that Static compression is enabled in IIS for the site in all three environments.
Many people have recommended disabling chunked Transfer-Encoding via the ASP portion of IIS and while we could do this, I’m not sure if it’s a good idea?

ASP is NOT installed on our production environment and our Sys Admin is understandably wary of installing it (so it appears in IIS) when we do not write anything in ASP.

I have also read about forcing http/1.0 rather than allowing http/1.1 but this seems like a cop-out and a rather inefficient one at that.

But is that our only option? And if so, is it worth it? Am I even going about this is the correct fashion?  I wanted to pre-compile the .gz files to eliminate any unneeded processing on our production server.

I’m not sure what other information I could provide to be helpful but I can gladly ass more info to this post if needed.

---

Example of .cfm that loads the CSS:

```
<cfparam name="URL.name" default="" />

<cfif Len( URL['name'] ) GT 0 AND Len( url.name ) LT 64 AND ReFind( url.name, "[^a-zA-Z\-\.\_]+" ) EQ 0>

    <cfif CGI['http_accept_encoding'] CONTAINS "gzip" AND FileExists( ExpandPath( './css/' & url.name & '.gz' ) )>

        <cfheader name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip" />
        <cfcontent reset="true" type="text/css" deletefile="no" file="#ExpandPath('./css/#url.name#.gz')#" />

    <cfelseif FileExists( ExpandPath( './css/#url.name#.css' ) )>

        <cfcontent reset="true" type="text/css" deletefile="no" file="#ExpandPath('./css/#url.name#.css')#" />

    </cfif>

</cfif>

<cfabort>
```